# Any kind of duality between differentials and Tate modules?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $X$ be a curve over some algebraically closed field $k$ and let $J$ be its Jacobian. I have read that one should think of the Tate module $T_lJ$ as being the first homology group of $X$ with coefficients on $\mathbb{Z}_l$.

Now in the classical case an important tool is to integrate differentials along elements of the homology group with integral coefficients. Is there anything similar one can do with differentials on $X$ and elements of the Tate module of $J$?

Comment: If the field in question is $\ell$-adic, one can do this with $p$-adic Hodge theory.

Comment: Or rather with $\ell$-adic Hodge theory...